# How to create temporary URLs for not showing video URL from view source in PHP

Tags: php, video-streaming

I want to create temporary url for my video site for not showing my actual video path to user ,so if he see in view source a temporary url shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. On each page load make an entry for a hash and the current timestamp.
2. Now when your code gets the path for your video file just put a check there with hash you have generated and the request timestamp.
3. And check if timestamp is old more than a limit you return 404 page or false.
4. If all is seems right do allow the file path to pass through.